How to create namespace alias for an NPM package?
I want to use figlet library that have types in @types/figlet. But the problem is that it only works for node module and I want to use with Docusaurus that use Webpack.
The project readme says that you can just import the package when using Webpack. But it doesn't work because it throws an error when figlet try to use __dirname.
The project package.json file have this:
  "main": "./lib/node-figlet.js",
  "browser": "./lib/figlet.js",

If I replace import figlet from 'figlet' with import figlet from 'figlet/lib/figlet.js' my code works, but TypeScript complain that there are no types for this import.
Is there a way to map 'figlet' types into 'figlet/lib/figlet.js'?
The types for @types/figlet have this code:
declare namespace figlet {
}

declare function figlet(txt: string, cb: (error: Error | null, result?: string) => void): void;
declare function figlet(txt: string, font: figlet.Fonts, cb: (error: Error | null, result?: string) => void): void;

declare function figlet(
    txt: string,
    // This `unified-signatures` is disabled because `Fonts` type is too long
    // tslint:disable-next-line: unified-signatures
    options: figlet.Options | undefined,
    cb: (error: Error | null, result?: string) => void,
): void;

export as namespace figlet;
export = figlet;

What I want to do is to import the types create different namespace and export everything from first namespace. Is something like this possible?
